# How to remove keywords in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove a single keyword `a`. However, if `ab` appear, it will not be removed.

For example, `acdabdeaefabba` becomes `cdabdeefabb`.

How to use regular expression to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), with a negative lookahead to remove `a` only when it is not followed by `b`:

```
s = 'acdabdeaefabba'
import re
re.sub('a(?!b)', '', s)
# 'cdabdeefabb'
```

Comment: Thanks, yatu. How about removing `b` only if its preceding character is not `a`?

Comment: In that case you can use `re.sub('(?<!a)b', '', s)`